Using min width with FractionallySizedBox
I need a container that has a width of 40% of the screen width and consists of 2 equal columns.
I tried to do it like this:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 300, minWidth: 450),
          color: Colors.green,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.4,
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1.5,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [Text('1'), Text('2'), Text('3')],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [Text('1'), Text('2'), Text('3')],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And the main container behaves as expected, but the columns keep shrinking to 40% of the screen width.
It's okay as long as the width is big enough

But when the container can't get any smaller, this happens

How can I avoid this and make the width of these columns depend solely on the width of the container?
Please follow this for better examples: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sg0IYTQxA7X5AX3Q2Mxoc7l5QfqMKchf

Why do you have the AspectRatio in there?  That's not in your textual description.  What happens when you remove it?

You can use alignment: Alignment.center,

@RandalSchwartz container expands to the height of the screen and the width does not change, which is generally expected

When you set minWidth to be at least 450, after making screen smaller, the container keeps its width to be 450 but according to the widthFactor, it shrink the children to get only 40% of screen width.
When you set the container to get 40% of screen width, there is no must to set minWidth to define how much the width should be. I recommend to use properties like maxWidth to restrict the width in bigger screens.
If you want to restrict the container width not to be smaller than 450 in smaller screens and also keep the width to get only 40% of screen width in bigger screens, you can follow this pattern:
import 'dart:math' as math;
LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          double containerWidth = constraints.maxWidth * 0.4;
          containerWidth = math.max(450, containerWidth);
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              width: containerWidth,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [Text('1'), Text('2'), Text('3')],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [Text('1'), Text('2'), Text('3')],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

I hope this pattern solve your problem, feel free to leave comment, if there is any ambiguity.

But i'm trying to limit the width for small screens. The columns will have content that can't take up too little space. At the same time too much space is not needed either. 40% of the screen width but not less than 450px seems right to me. however when i start filling the columns with widgets this happens.
Please follow this (google drive link) to see what i am talking about:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sg0IYTQxA7X5AX3Q2Mxoc7l5QfqMKchf

@kos1posha I have edited my previous code according to your comment
